# Is there any way to call a particular function from a href in same page in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

Is there any way to call a particular function from `a href` in same page in `jsp??`

My jsp code is:

```
<%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1></H1>
    <TABLE>
       <%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable;") ;  %>
        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <TR>
            <script>
function <%=resultset.getString(1)%>() {
   //////// Here i want to display data related to that particular link
}
</script>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="<%=resultset.getString(1)%>;" href="#"><%=resultset.getString(1)%></a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>
        <% } %>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Suppose my link name which i am getting from `resulset.getString(1)` is `Audio`, then i want that after clicking on Audio the function named Audio should get called and print some data inside it. I don't want to provide function names manually because i am getting around 20 names from `resultset.getString(1)`.
Please help me.

Comment: Please add code, which function do you want to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet. pass counter as function argument and write logic in switch case for all 20 cases.

```
<script>
 function displayData(ctr) {
           //////// Here i want to display data related to that particular link
   switch (ctr) {
    case 0:
        alert("function 1");
        //write function logic here
        break;
    case 1:
       alert("function 2");
         break;
    case 19:
       alert("function 20");
        break;
         }
    }
</script>
     <TABLE>
               <%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable;") ;  %>
                <% 
                int counter=0;
                 while(resultset.next()){ 
                    String link=resultset.getString(1);
                    counter++;
                %>
                <TR>

                   <TD>

                       <a onclick="displayData(<%=counter%>);" href="#"><%=link%></a>
                   </TD> 
                </TR>
                <% } %>
      </TABLE>
```

Comment: In resultset i am getting more than 20 elements, and for each link i want to call different functions. Your code will give same results for all the links.

Comment: You need a counter variable and a single javascript function outside the loop with counter as parameter. you just need to call the function with parameter. inside the function you manipulate using switch case of counter and write logic for each case.

Comment: can u please show it in code please please please, i am literally new to jsp

Comment: Please help me i am really stucked

Comment: No its working for only first link , also i don't want alert as it shows the output in dialog box

Comment: alert is just a sample. you have to write your logic. how can i? check what parameter value is passed inside the function.